# Negative reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, users

Let us see this screen (29th November 2013):

[image]

I know that Marien..., oh, Donut E. Knot, has many names and this is a source of a strange value. But should I communicate such behaviour of the platform as a bug or think about it as of a pretty joke?

Comment: What's the concern here? Falls in rep for periods other than 'all time registered' are quite possible.

Comment: I just want to know what browser plugin you used to see things 90 years in the future. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn :-) Corrected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a bug, but accurately reflects the reputation gained *over a particular period of time*.  If you look at the Users page you can select the period of time:

[image: rep period]

So it's entirely possible for a user who gives a lot of bounties to have a negative reputation when calculated over one of these smaller time periods.

Comment: I understand now: a change of reputation is called reputation on the page; hence my naive question.

Comment: If you asked me, that page has confused me couple times over the time, so you're not the first one ;)